# Cannot find symbol class RecyclerView Item Listener

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have two fragments with almost identical RecyclerViews, but on the second one, Android Studio is giving me  an error that it "cannot find symbol class LessonItemListener".

```
ui\detail\DetailFragment.java:6: error: cannot find symbol public final class DetailFragment extends androidx.fragment.app.Fragment implements ... ui.detail.LessonRecyclerAdapter.LessonItemListener {

     symbol:   class LessonItemListener
     location: class LessonRecyclerAdapter
```

This is the beginning of the fragment that gives me that error:

```
class DetailFragment : Fragment(), LessonRecyclerAdapter.LessonItemListener {

    private lateinit var viewModel: SharedViewModel
    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var navController: NavController
.
.
.
```

This is the other fragment with almost identical code but works fine:

```
class CourseFragment : Fragment(), CourseRecyclerAdapter.CourseItemListener {

    private lateinit var viewModel: SharedViewModel
    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var navController: NavController
    .
    .
    .
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by deleted the implement LessonRecyclerAdapter.LessonItemListener and its onLessonItemClick() function and retyped it again and it worked.

I guess it could be an Android Studio bug.